# BadMethodCallException: Project does not exist error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: projects and product

The problem is i cannot add new products from a project (one to many relationship)

I get the following error after creating a project with products: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::project does not exist.

I need help solving this problem

Product.php

```
<?php
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Project::class);
    }
}
```

Project.php

```
<?php

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
```

Product migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        if(!Schema::hasTable('product')){
            Schema::create('product', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->text('description')->nullable();
                $table->float('price')->nullable();

                $table->foreignId('project_id')->nullable()->constrained('project')->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product');
    }
};
```

ProjectController.php

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $project = new Project;

        $project->name = $request->name;
        $project->start_date = $request->start_date;
        $project->due_date = $request->due_date;
        $project->completed_date = $request->completed_date;
        $project->actual_days = $request->actual_days;
        $project->public_notes = $request->public_notes;
        $project->private_notes = $request->private_notes;
        $project->customer_id = $request->customer_id;
        $project->project_category_id = $request->project_category_id;
        $project->status = $request->status;
        $project->user_id = $request->user_id;

       // $project->products()->associate($request->products);
        
        $products = Product::find($request->products);
        // $products->project()->associate($project);

        $products->project()->save($products);
        
        //$project->products()->associate($project->id);

    }
```

Comment: Try `$products->project->save($products);` instead, without the `()`. It may work.

Comment: @ericmp Tried, didnt work. Got this error: Property [project] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: So the thing you want to achieve is to validate requested project and products, and then create them? If so, first do a proper validation - https://laravel.com/docs/validation. After that, just store the validated data - https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserts. And what do you want to in this line? `$products = Product::find($request->products);`

Comment: @ericmp Get all the product that are selected from project. User can add multiple products from projects.

Comment: Afaik `Model::find()` expects the id of the model that you want to find in the db, can be only 1 id or an array of ids. So I guess you don't want to find anything in the store method, or do you want? Not sure what logic you want to apply here

Comment: @ericmp I'm trying to get an array of product ids and then save the created project with all the products that are added. Since there are mulitple products, I have to get an array of product ids

Comment: Your Relationships: Your products belong to a Project Not having a project. Try this out and see how to move from there. 

``` <?php
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
 ```

Comment: @XeusKing Same issue. I think the problem is in Product::find which returns an array of multiple products. I cannot access project model from an array.